# Download / Upload Gmail Filters XML file

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, gmail-api

I would like to be able to download the Gmail filters XML file (Accessed by going to Settings  > Filters and Blocked Addresses > Export), and also to be able to reupload it after making changes. After looking through the Google API, there doesn't seem to be any way to do this.

I will be using python to manipulate the XML file, but I would like to be able to download the file before I start.

Answer (score 1):

The ability to us the Gmail API to download the filters as XML and the upload them back for it to be modified is not available, you could submit a feature request to their issue tracker at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191602&template=824107

### Possible workaround:

Google only offers the option to retrieve all filters into a `dict`, using their [QuickStart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) I made this snippet that would retrieve all filters:

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic']
...
    try:
        # Call the Gmail API
        service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
        results = service.users().settings().filters().list(userId='me').execute()
        print(results)
        

    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from gmail API.
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')
```

The output would be similar to this one:

```
{
    "filter": [
        {
            "id": "aaaaaaaaaaaaBBBBBBBBBBBBZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ",
            "criteria": {"from": "google-workspace-alerts-noreply@google.com"},
            "action": {"addLabelIds": ["Label_ID"]},
        }
    ]
}
```

It also seems impossible to modify an existing filter using the API, at the moment you'll need to delete the filter that you want to update and then create it again:

#### Delete:

```
    try:
        # Call the Gmail API
        service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
        results = service.users().settings().filters().delete(userId='me',id='aaaaaaaaaaaaBBBBBBBBBBBBZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ').execute()
        print(results)
```

#### Create:

```
    try:
        service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
        filter = {
            'criteria': {"from": "google-workspace-alerts-noreply@google.com"},
            'action': {"addLabelIds": ["Label_ID"]},
        }
        results = service.users().settings().filters().create(userId='me',body=filter).execute()
        print(results)
```

---

#### Some documentation:

- [Filter Schema.](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.filters) Note that there are only 3 options for actions while the Gmail UI contains more. The Gmail API looks a limited when managing filters at the moment.
- [Labels in the Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.labels)